# Improve performance of inserting data for one to many relationship in EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, database-design

I am getting really poor performance in EF because of a particular design structure for my database. Here are the relevant relationships:

---

[image: ERD]

---

I have the following data model:

---

```
public class Sensor
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(64)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("Type")]
    public int SensorTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual SensorType Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SensorSample> SensorSamples { get; set; }
}

public class SensorSample
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("Sensor")]
    public int SensorId { get; set; }

    public virtual Sensor Sensor { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime SampleTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<SampleData> SampleData { get; set; }
}

public class SampleData
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("DataType")]
    public int SampleDataTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual SampleDataType DataType { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("Unit")]
    public int SampleUnitId { get; set; }

    public virtual SampleUnit Unit { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("Sample")]
    public int SensorSampleId { get; set; }

    public virtual SensorSample Sample { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

---

Because a `SensorSample` can have multiple data sample types (i.e. temperature, pressure, etc), an `INSERT` must query for existing samples to make the appropriate association with the correct `SampleTime`. This is done using the following code:

---

```
SensorSample sample = null;
foreach (var d in input)
{
    SampleData data = new SampleData();
    data.SampleDataTypeId = dataTypeId;
    data.SampleUnitId = unitId;
    data.Value = d.Value;

    // check for existing sample for this sensor and timestamp
    sample = SensorSamples.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SensorId == sensor.Id && s.SampleTime == d.Timestamp);
    if (sample == null)
    {
        // sample doesn't exist, create a new one
        sample = new SensorSample();
        sample.SampleTime = d.Timestamp;
        sample.SensorId = sensor.Id;
        sensor.SensorSamples.Add(sample);
    }
    // add the data to the sample
    sample.SampleData.Add(data);
}
```

---

I have tried optimizing the inserting of sample data by doing it in batches (i.e. 1000 records at a time). This does help, but even though there is an index on the `SampleTime` field, the lookup query seems to take longer as more records are added.

So, my question is, how do I improve the design and/or performance of adding sample data to the database? Is there a better database structure for handling the one-to-many relationship? I am willing to make some compromises on database design if I can get an appropriate offset in performance, but I still need to be able to handle different data associated with a given `SampleTime`.

Comment: Did you already try the infamous `context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` setting (directly after context creation)?

Comment: Also, is it possible to enable the profiler in SQL Management Studio for SQL Server 2012 Express? Or is that only available in the paid for SQL Server versions?

Comment: Never mind. Found this: [http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/](http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/).

Comment: What is the "input" variable? Is it an in memory collection? Do you know the minimum and/or maximum Timestamp within it? Could you load all the SensorSamples within that range into memory rather than go to the database one by one?

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework maintains a local cache of all the local entities, and tracks any changes are made in those entities. As the number of entities grows, the checking gets more expensive.

[Here](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/10/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-1-what-does-detectchanges-do/) is a very interesting post series on how does DetectChanges work and what can you do about it. Look especially in part 3.

When I need to bulk load a lot of data I disable DetectChanges and also clear the local cache after saving, so that memory can be freed:

```
    public static void ClearDbSet<T>(this DbContext context) where T : class {
        var entries = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Unchanged);

        foreach (DbEntityEntry<T> entry in entries.ToList()) {
            entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
        }
    }
```

The `ToList` call is necessary otherwise the iterator will throw an exception.

Comment: Reviewing the linked article. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

to maximize LOAD performance for test data

```
    DONT run project in Debug mode (multiple factor slower for EF)
```

use these settings:

```
    Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    Context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    Context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    Context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

every 100 entries or fewer, discard Context.

```
 Using( new context)
```

try

```
Context.Set<TPoco>().AddOrUpdate(poco);
```

Instead of

```
   Context.Set<TPoco>().firstorDefault(lamba);
   Context.Set<TPoco>().Add(poco);
```

Comment: Take care with AddOrUpdate - http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/

Comment: These are great suggestions and I was at the point of trying some of them before I posted my question, but wanted feedback first. I do discard the context when bulk inserting in batch mode. My biggest concern is the query that has to happen to check for an existing `SensorSample` to either add the data to the existing one or create a new one. I think that removing that restriction could speed things up dramatically but would require a non-normalized database structure change.

Answer (score 0):

EF6 beta 1 has an AddRange function that may suit your purpose:

[INSERTing many rows with Entity Framework 6 beta 1](http://sql.dzone.com/articles/inserting-many-rows-entity)

Note that the article I link to refers to the technique of setting AutoDetectChangesEnabled to false in EF5 that @felipe refers to

Comment: Anyone have an idea of release schedule for EF 6? I haven't looked at any of the proposed changes yet.

Comment: "This year" i.e 2013 - http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/31/ef6-release-datesor-lack-thereof/