# Fast Mapping and inserting to table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I am loading a list of objects, need to map those objects and store it back to another database. Those two tables don't have the same schema, so a mapping is necessary.
For example:

```
using (var db1 = new Db1())
{
    var customers = db1.CustomersDb1;

    using (var db2 = new Db2())
    {
        foreach (var customer in customers)
        {
            var c = Mapper.Map<CustomerDb2>(customer);
            db2.customers.Add(c);
        }
        db2.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Now i tested this piece of code with round about **12000** entries and it lasted **2-3 minutes** just until i reach `db2.SaveChanges()`. So i even haven't stored anything after this time.
The `Customer` object in `Db2` just has 14 properties so i don't exactly know where it needs this much time.

Is there a faster way to map and copy two tables with `Entity Framework`?

**EDIT:**
The most time is needed in the loop. So it's not a problem of the database. And it also doesn't matter if i use `automapper` or if i map it manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is faster: Automapper, Valuinjector, or manual mapping? To what degree is each one faster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122334/which-is-faster-automapper-valuinjector-or-manual-mapping-to-what-degree-is)

Comment: Map them manually or with another mapper, compare the result and pick the fastest.

Comment: @CodeCaster it doesn't matter how i map it, i edited my question.

Comment: You might benefit from researching alternative methods for bulk inserts (I don't know how to do that with EF off the top of my head). For example, `SqlBulkCopy` or perhaps NHibernates stateless sessions combined with a GuidComb. I am going to assume that most of the CPU time is spent tracking/housekeeping the 12000 objects passing through EF.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead thanks for your comment. i debugged and took time. Most of the time really is lost with adding the object to Entity Framework. Maybe there is no faster solution.

Comment: have you checked these?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497238/improve-performance-of-inserting-data-for-one-to-many-relationship-in-ef    and     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274430/efficient-way-to-do-bulk-insert-update-with-entity-framework

Comment: Another way besides SqlBulkCopy are ETL products like SSIS and RhinoETL

Answer (score 0):

Don't use EF. Use just a single SQL statement.

```
INSERT INTO Db1.Customers (ID, Value1, Value2)
SELECT NEWID(), Value1, Value2 FROM Db2.Customers

GO
```